# Selenium IDE - AJAX text field not updating

Tags: ajax, selenium, selenium-ide

I am testing a payment page where once you enter an amount paid and leave that field, the total paid field updates.

The problem is, even though Selenium is entering data into the amount paid field, the total paid field still says 0.00.

I have tried clicking into other fields, entering text into other fields, using sendKeys and keyPress for TAB, Enter, highlighting other areas of the page, and nothing seems to be working.

There is a validation on the page that requires a minimum amount paid before you continue, therefore, I cannot go forward at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the fireEvent/blur on the amount paid field after entering the data.

HTML looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=checkAmount</td>
    <td>${Amount}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>fireEvent</td>
    <td>id=checkAmount</td>
    <td>focus</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>fireEvent</td>
    <td>id=checkAmount</td>
    <td>blur</td>
</tr>
```